# Check from view if the action was rendered as partialview or view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

How can i check if my action was rendered as a partialview or a view?
I'm using `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` but i don't know if this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the follwoing property is better than Request.IsAjaxRequest()

```
ViewContext.View.RunViewStartPages
```